# Javascript: Add player to a specific object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm making an application where a user can create a team and add players to it, to track team stats.

In my code, I have an array of teams, a function to create a team and a function to create a player.

I want `createNewPlayer()` to accept a team variable, so it adds the player to the wright team.

Now, the function returns the "Team does not exist", while I created a team with that exact name before running the function.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

```
const Teams = []

// Team Class
class Team {
    constructor(name, players) {
        this.name = name;
        this.players = [];
    }
}

// Player class
class Player {  
    constructor(name, lastName, team, goal, assist, yellowCard, redCard, minPlayed) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.team = team;
        this.goal = 0;
        this.assist = 0;
        this.yellowCard = 0;
        this.redCard = 0;
        this.minPlayed = 0;
    }
}

// Create new team
const createNewTeam = (name) => {
    if (typeof name === "string") {
        let newTeam = new Team(name);
        Teams.push(newTeam);
    } else {
        console.log("Something went wrong.");
    }
}

//Create new player
const createNewPlayer = (name, lastName, team) => {
    let newPlayer = new Player(name, lastName, team);
    for (i = 0; i < Teams.length; i++) {
        if (Teams[i].name === team) {
            Teams[i].players.push(newPlayer);
        } else {
            console.log("Team does not exist!")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop over all the teams, and in every iteration in which the team name does not match, you log the error.
You should try something like this:

```
let teamFound = false;
for (i = 0; i < Teams.length; i++) {
    if (Teams[i].name === team) {
        Teams[i].players.push(newPlayer);
        teamFound = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (!teamFound) {
    console.log("Team does not exist!")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check for `Teams[i].name == team.name` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this:

```
const createNewPlayer = (name, lastName, teamName) => {
  let newPlayer = new Player(name, lastName, teamName);
  let team = Teams.find((Team) => Team.name === teamName)
  if(team !== undefined) {
    team.players.push
  } else {
    console.log("Team does not exist!")
  }
  return newPlayer
}
```